# Can all neural network with DAG topology be trained by Back-prop?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, dag

Can all neural network having directed acyclic graph (DAG) topology be trained by back propagation methods? You can assume that the activation functions of all neurons are differentiable.

I mean by the gradient based methods like Stochastic gradient decent, AdaGrad,Adam, etc.

If it's true, is there a reference (academic paper is the best) providing the proof of it?

Answer (score 2):

> Can all neural network having directed acyclic graph (DAG) topology be trained by back propagation methods? I mean by the back propagation methods like Stochastic gradient decent, AdaGrad, Adam, etc.

The methods you mention are gradient-based, and subsequently won't work if one activation function used by the artificial neurons isn't differentiable. However, they are some ways around, e.g. [using reinforcement learning](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/).

Comment: I updated the question to add the assumption that all activation functions are differentiabla

Comment: Reinforcement learning says it uses Back-Propagation for weights update...